# All test cases are not exported using "Test Case Export to Excel"

Tags: excel, tfs, export, testcase, microsoft-test-manager

When I use "Test Case Export to Excel" at http://exporttfs2excel.codeplex.com/ , it's very strange that 
- All the test cases is not exported
- The Pass/Fail result is not exported as well
Can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved, Test cases without test steps won't be exported